# JS file not loaded in the html with flask

Tags: flask

My project's structure is this (i am obliged to keep img folder, index.html, setup.js under the same folder because of chessboards.js):

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 usertest  staff       96 Dec  7 18:02 img
-rw-r--r--@ 1 usertest  staff     1075 Dec 11 11:58 index.html
-rw-r--r--  1 usertest  staff      561 Dec 11 11:55 main.py
-rw-r--r--  1 usertest  staff     2631 Dec 11 11:25 setup.js
```

index.html is just including some js libs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chessboard Example</title>
    <!-- Include chess.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chess.js/0.10.2/chess.js"></script>

    <!-- Include chessboard.js -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@chrisoakman/chessboardjs@1.0.0/dist/chessboard-1.0.0.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@chrisoakman/chessboardjs@1.0.0/dist/chessboard-1.0.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include the external JavaScript file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="setup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="board1" style="width: 400px"></div>
    <!-- Buttons for interacting with the chessboard -->
    <button id="startBtn">Start Position</button>
    <button id="clearBtn">Clear Board</button>
    <button id="undoBtn">Undo Move</button>
    <button id="moveBtn">Next best move</button>

</body>
</html>
```

And main.py looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


flask_app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='')


@flask_app.route('/')
def chess_index(): 
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    flask_app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

When i am loading the page it says that the setup.js is not found. I have already cleared the cache multiple times and i don't understand what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you will need to declare the path to your static files directly in the flask constructor, like this:

```
flask_app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', template_folder='')
```

Note the addition of the parameter `static_url_path` which can be used to specify a different path for the static files on the web. Defaults to the name of the `static_folder` folder, wich is the folder with static files that is served at static_url_path. Relative to the application root_path or an absolute path. Defaults to 'static'.

[For more details](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/)